# How to append multiple materials from different blend files

Tags: materials, append

I am making a material library file, how can I append multiple materials at once to the file? (each material is in a different file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Blender 2.76 you'll be able to set how many directory levels to show simultaneously.

You can download the last build, though it was not as stable as release:
https://builder.blender.org/download/

It works both for system folder and blender file data

[image]

Let's say your blend files are all in the same directory.

Choose *One Level* and filter by material:

[image]

You'll find all the materials used in all the blend files.

[image]